# Why can't I create this class object in Java? Giving me Cannot find symbol

Tags: java, class, object

So I wrote a simple class defining what a complex number is and methods to add, subtract, multiply, divide, but when I try to create a class object of type ComplexNumber in a different class with a main method, I get compiler errors that say it 'cannot find symbol'. Almost like the main method class can't see the ComplexNumber class. I even put them in the same package to make sure of this, and Yes, I've compiled the ComplexNumber class before attemtping to compile the main method class.

This is the class with the sub,mult,div methods removed for sanity's sake:

*** Edit: Okay, dumping both entire classes for clarity

```
package CN001;

public class ComplexNumber {

private float a;
private float b;

public ComplexNumber(float _a, float _b) {
    this.a = _a;
    this.b = _b;
}

public float getA(){
    return this.a;
}

public float getB(){
    return this.b;
}

public ComplexNumber complexNumberAdd(ComplexNumber otherNumber){
    ComplexNumber newComplex;
    float newA = a + otherNumber.getA();
    float newB = b + otherNumber.getB();
    newComplex = new ComplexNumber(newA, newB);
    return newComplex;
}
}
```

And this is the main class:

```
package CN001;

public class ComplexNumberRunner {

public static void main (String[] args){
float _a;
float _b;

ComplexNumber addComplex = new ComplexNumber(_a,_b);
}
}
```

Comment: when im compiled evrything is ok , so it's maybe for your wrong classpath...

Comment: Is it compile error or runtime? Do you include a classpath on the command line when running it? Do you include the class in the classpath?

Comment: @cbpickl you use commandline?!!!
what your writed when you compile your code?!

Comment: It's a compiler error. I don't include a classpath on the command line, I didn't think that was necessary? Do I need a to include a classpath when creating the object or something? I'm new to programming, so I'm sorry. :( Professor wants us using gedit and command line to code, don't know why.

Comment: @cbpickl : for classpath read this link after than if you again have problem write here 

http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the _a and _b local variable names with the actual values you want to initialise it with. Something like:

```
ComplexNumber addComplex = new ComplexNumber(3, 5);
```

Comment: The problem seems to be more endemic than that, no matter what I change in the parameter field while trying to create the object, the compiler keeps giving 'cannot find symbol' errors referring to ComplexNumber. Like it can't see the class.

Comment: @cbpickl The compiler has to have this class's base directory in its classpath. How are you compiling it? Through an IDE or from a command line? Are both classes in the default package?

Comment: Both classes are in the same folder, and I even added them to the same package to make extra sure. I'm compiling from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need define _a and _b as float and initialize it and after than write ,

```
ComplexNumber addComplex = new ComplexNumber(_a,_b);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, no luck. Declared _a and _b as floats, the problem seems to be more endemic. The compiler error keeps getting hung up on 'cannot find symbol' referring to ComplexNumber

Comment: @cbpickl you use commandline?!!! what your writed when you want to compile your code?!